# Warm up Scripts in sharepoint 2013 - Load balanced

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm just launching new web apps on a new built web farm.But it seems when i first load the pages in the morning its quite slow to load and shows working on it.
I need a very simple reliable warm p script that i schedule.
We are using a load balancer. I have came across some in the web but i need some advice from anyone that is also in this situation and their thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a powershell script for this. Below is a script that works like a charm!

```
Get-SPWebApplication | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-WebRequest $_.url -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing }
```

For more info: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=404